# For frame [velodyne]: Frame [velodyne] does not exist

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I was trying to run the demo at the [autoware.ai github](https://github.com/Autoware-AI/autoware.ai/wiki/ROSBAG-Demo).

After I applied the `my_map.launch` , I still cannot see the pointcloud map in RVIZ.

The RVIZ  is shown as follows:

[image: oTtEb8.png]

The points_raw had the error: `For frame [velodyne]: Frame [velodyne] does not exist`

I'm using ros melodic and autoware 1.14.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/392639/for-frame-%5Bvelodyne%5D:-frame-%5Bvelodyne%5D-does-not-exist/) by [changhao](https://answers.ros.org/users/54202/changhao/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2021-12-10

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The frame `velodyne` would generally be a frame for a lidar - specifically a Velodyne lidar. This is the "frame of reference" in which the lidar data are published (the `frame_id` field of the `PointCloud2` messages). In order for RViz to visualize data from your lidar while also showing the map, there must be a transform (or multiple transforms, in this case) to get from the frame of the lidar to the map frame. This error is telling you that the frame named `velodyne` is not connected to the frame in which you're viewing data in RViz (you can find this by expanding "Global Options" at the top of the left frame) - I'm assuming `map`. These transforms can be published individually by instances of the `static_transform_publisher` node but are usually combined into a URDF file which describes multiple frames and the relationships between them. This URDF file can then be loaded by a `robot_state_publisher` node and will automatically publish all of the described transforms. In general, a lidar fixed to a vehicle would have a transform to `map` which would consist of: `velodyne` -> `base_link` -> `odom` -> `map`. For more information, see https://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0105.html.

---

Originally posted by [Josh Whitley](https://answers.ros.org/users/4390/josh-whitley/) with karma: 1766 on 2021-12-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1